# Cannot import installed packages in Jupyter Notebook using Miniforge Conda Environment on M1 Mac

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, conda, apple-silicon

I have a M1 Mac (Apple Silicon, ARM) and I followed the instructions given by Apple [here](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos/issues/153) to install Miniforge, create a conda environment called `tf_env` and install Tensorflow on it.

I wanted to use Jupyter Notebooks with the `tf_env` environment so after activating the environment, I run `conda install -c anaconda ipykernel` which worked successfully. Next, I typed `jupyter notebook` and a window opened in Safari. I created a new Jupyter notebook but I can't seem to import any of the packages (e.g. `numpy` or `tensorflow`). I get this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d4cdadb62aa7> in <module>
----> 1 import numpy

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I did some sanity checks:

- Am I running the correct Conda environemnt? Running `!echo $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV` in a cell returns `tf_env`.
- Are the packages installed? Running `!conda list` in a cell returns the following.

```
# packages in environment at /Users/maurocamara/miniforge3/envs/tf_env:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
absl-py                   0.13.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
aiohttp                   3.7.4.post0      py38hea4295b_0    conda-forge
appnope                   0.1.2            py38h10201cd_1    conda-forge
astor                     0.8.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
astunparse                1.6.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
async-timeout             3.0.1                   py_1000    conda-forge
attrs                     21.2.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
blinker                   1.4                        py_1    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38hea4295b_1001    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.17.1               h27ca646_1    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2021.5.30            h4653dfc_0    conda-forge
cached-property           1.5.2                hd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
cached_property           1.5.2              pyha770c72_1    conda-forge
cachetools                4.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2021.5.30        py38h10201cd_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.14.6           py38h0957451_0    conda-forge
chardet                   4.0.0            py38h10201cd_1    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        2.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
click                     8.0.1            py38h10201cd_0    conda-forge
cryptography              3.4.7            py38h3c0dae5_0    conda-forge
dataclasses               0.8                pyhc8e2a94_1    conda-forge
debugpy                   1.3.0            py38h6f2b01f_0    conda-forge
decorator                 5.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
gast                      0.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
google-auth               1.33.1             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.1                      py_2    conda-forge
google-pasta              0.2.0              pyh8c360ce_0    conda-forge
grpcio                    1.38.1           py38h69ee544_0    conda-forge
h5py                      3.3.0           nompi_py38hb525b2d_100    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.6          nompi_h0fc092c_1114    conda-forge
idna                      3.1                pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        4.6.1            py38h10201cd_0    conda-forge
ipykernel                 6.0.3            py38h2cb4d76_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.25.0           py38h2cb4d76_1    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
jedi                      0.18.0           py38h10201cd_2    conda-forge
jupyter_client            6.1.7                      py_0    anaconda
jupyter_core              4.7.1            py38h10201cd_0    conda-forge
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
krb5                      1.19.1               hd92b7a7_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0                9_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0                9_openblas    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.77.0               h8fe1914_0    conda-forge
libcxx                    12.0.1               h168391b_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         hc8eb9b7_2    conda-forge
libev                     4.33                 h642e427_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.3                  h9f76cd9_2    conda-forge
libgfortran               5.0.0.dev0      11_0_1_hf114ba7_22    conda-forge
libgfortran5              11.0.1.dev0         hf114ba7_22    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0                9_openblas    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.43.0               hf3018f0_0    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.15          openmp_hf330de4_1    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.17.2               hccf11d3_1    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h27ca646_1    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.9.0                hb80f160_6    conda-forge
llvm-openmp               12.0.1               hf3c4609_0    conda-forge
markdown                  3.3.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
multidict                 5.1.0            py38hea4295b_1    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.2                  h9aa5885_4    conda-forge
numpy                     1.21.1           py38hbf7bb01_0    conda-forge
oauthlib                  3.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1k               h27ca646_0    conda-forge
opt_einsum                3.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pip                       20.2.4                     py_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.19             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  3.17.2           py38h6f2b01f_0    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pyasn1                    0.4.8                      py_0    conda-forge
pyasn1-modules            0.2.7                      py_0    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.20               pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pygments                  2.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyjwt                     2.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 20.0.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1            py38h10201cd_3    conda-forge
python                    3.8.10          hf9733c0_1_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0    anaconda
python-flatbuffers        2.0                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.8                      2_cp38    conda-forge
pyu2f                     0.1.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyzmq                     22.1.0           py38h51b17a6_0    conda-forge
readline                  8.1                  hedafd6a_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.26.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
rsa                       4.7.2              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
scipy                     1.7.0            py38hd0c9ec0_0    conda-forge
setuptools                49.6.0           py38h10201cd_3    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.36.0               h72a2b83_0    conda-forge
tensorboard               2.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.0              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
tensorflow                2.4.0rc0                 pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-addons         0.11.2                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.5.0              pyh81a9013_1    conda-forge
tensorflow-probability    0.7                        py_1    conda-forge
termcolor                 1.1.0                      py_2    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.10               hf7e6567_1    conda-forge
tornado                   6.1              py38hea4295b_1    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.0.5                      py_0    conda-forge
typeguard                 2.12.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         3.10.0.0             hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         3.10.0.0           pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.6             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
werkzeug                  2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
wrapt                     1.12.1           py38hea4295b_3    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                h642e427_1    conda-forge
yarl                      1.6.3            py38hea4295b_2    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.4                h9f76cd9_0    conda-forge
zipp                      3.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h31e879b_1009    conda-forge
```

- Running `!conda info` I get

```
     active environment : tf_env
    active env location : /Users/maurocamara/miniforge3/envs/tf_env
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/maurocamara/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/maurocamara/miniforge3/.condarc
                          /Users/maurocamara/.condarc
          conda version : 4.10.3
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.9.6.final.0
       virtual packages : __osx=11.2.3=0
                          __unix=0=0
                          __archspec=1=arm64
       base environment : /Users/maurocamara/miniforge3  (writable)
      conda av data dir : /Users/maurocamara/miniforge3/etc/conda
  conda av metadata url : None
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
          package cache : /Users/maurocamara/miniforge3/pkgs
                          /Users/maurocamara/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/maurocamara/miniforge3/envs
                          /Users/maurocamara/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-arm64
             user-agent : conda/4.10.3 requests/2.26.0 CPython/3.9.6 Darwin/20.3.0 OSX/11.2.3
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

Comment: IMPORTANT: In the terminal, after activating `tf_env` if I run `python` (or `python3`) then I can import both numpy and tensorflow easily

Comment: I am having this same issue. Did you ever figure it out @Euler_Salter?

Comment: @Gamecocks It was a while ago but now it's working. I think I deleted everything and tried again. I also shut down the laptop so maybe that helped too?